# jQuery - picture snaps to wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens is, when you click on Img2, it does the animation, but afterwards Img3 just snaps to the left of Img1! I don't know why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.left', function() {
    $idr = $('.right').attr("id")
    $idl = $('.left').attr("id")
    $idt = $('.top').attr("id")
    $('#' + $idl).animate({
      'margin-top': '0',
      'width': '500'
    }, 650, function() {
      $('#' + $idl).removeClass('left').addClass('top')
    })
    $('#' + $idt).animate({
      'margin-left': '253',
      'margin-top': '358',
      'width': '247'
    }, 650, function() {
      $('#' + $idt).removeClass('top').addClass('right')
    })
    $('#' + $idr).animate({
      'margin-left': '0'
    }, 650, function() {
      $('#' + $idr).removeClass('right').addClass('left')
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#img2 {
  margin-top: 358px;
  width: 247px;
}
#img3 {
  margin-top: 358px;
  margin-left: 253px;
  width: 247px;
}
#slider {
  width: 504px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <img id="img1" class="top" draggable="false" src="http://s9.postimg.org/ygz34rwv3/pr1.jpg">
  <img id="img2" class="left" draggable="false" src="http://s9.postimg.org/c2heoju3j/pr2.jpg">
  <img id="img3" class="right" draggable="false" src="http://s9.postimg.org/rch9vqplr/pr3.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens because top image is not absolutely positioned so after animation it occupies space. You can fix it by adding position property to the `.top` class:

```
.top, .left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z3neveug/2/

Here is [one more version](http://jsfiddle.net/z3neveug/3/) of the same with a little refactored javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline;` to your `.left, .right` pseudo-classes.

Also, add this rule:

```
.left {
    left:0
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t6u6h6x9/1/**